# AngularJS 4 ng Bootstrap - typeahead: use of [resultTemplate] can only handle a string?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

AngularJS 4 ng Bootstrap - typeahead: use of resultTemplate can only handle a string?

I want to do something like

```
[resultTemplate]="getMyTemplateString()"
```

But this causes weird broken render of a template.

The example only shows:

```
[resultTemplate]="rt"
```

which works.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples. "rt" is a id of a component

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/' + r['flag']" width="16">
  {{ r.name}}
</ng-template>
```

ng-template **#rt**

So you can also handle a string.